# Job objects - To suspend / resume threads of the process

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, visual-c++

Can job objects ( created through CreateJobObject ) be used to suspend and resume threads of the process managed by the job ( similar to killing the process managed by the job using TerminateJobObject )?

-Karthik

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It is possible to get a similar effect with JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION and a hard limit of zero on the rate.

Comment: @John, from MSDN: "CpuRate should not be set to 0. If CpuRate is set to 0, SetInformationJobObject will return INVALID_ARGS."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit CPU usage you might want to set `JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION.PriorityClass` pre Win8 and `JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION` on Win8.

Suspending on a per thread basis usually does not make any sense since you don't usually know what each thread is doing.

It has nothing to do with job objects but if your target is WinXP+ you can use the undocumented NtSuspendProcess/NtResumeProcess functions to suspend/resume all threads in a process ( `NTSTATUS __stdcall NTDLL::NtSuspendProcess(HANDLE hProcess)` ). The windows debugging functions might come in handy if you need to support older systems...